# Why does chaining .map() and .filter() in Kotlin not work as expected?

Tags: functional-programming, kotlin, java-stream

I am trying to map a list of objects to a list of objects of another type, then filter the list, then map to a list of a third type, just like I would do by chaining streams in Java 8+ (I changed the class and variable names to make it more meaningful but the structure is the same as in my code):

```
val results: List<AccountDto> = listOfPersons
                .map { person -> getPersonAccount(person) }
                .filter { account ->
                    if(validateAccount(account)){ // validateAccount is a function with boolean return type
                        // do something here like logging
                        return true
                    }
                    // do something else...
                    return false
                }
                .map { account ->
                     toDto(account) // returns an AccountDto
                }
```

I get a compiler error on the `return true` and `return false` statements inside the filter lambda :

```
Error:(217, 32) Kotlin: The boolean literal does not conform to the expected type List<AccountDto>
```

If I use an anonymous function for the filter predicate it compiles fine :

```
.filter (fun(account):Boolean{
                if(validateAccount(account)){ 
                        // do something here like logging
                        return true
                    }
                    // do something else...
                    return false
            })
```

Why does the type inference fail in that case?

Is it possible to somehow I make it work with just a lambda ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`return` returns from the nearest enclosing function or anonymous function (that's the form `fun(a1: T1, ..., an: TN): TR = ...`) . The mnemonic is that an unqualified `return` goes up to the nearest `fun`. A lambda is not an anonymous function, so the `return` is actually returning from the function that contains the whole `map`/`filter` expression. You can use a labelled return:

```
val results: List<AccountDto> = listOfPersons
                .map(::getPersonAccount)
                .filter { account ->
                    if(validateAccount(account)){
                        // etc.
                        return@filter true
                    }
                    // etc.
                    return@filter false
                }
                .map(::toDto)
```

A lambda expression is implicitly labelled with the function that it is passed to, so you don't need to add the label explicitly. If you would prefer to have it, you may:

```
val results: List<AccountDto> = listOfPersons
                .map(::getPersonAccount)
                .filter lam@{ account ->
                    if(validateAccount(account)){
                        // etc.
                        return@lam true
                    }
                    // etc.
                    return@lam false
                }
                .map(::toDto)
```

But an `if`/`else` is itself an expression, so it suffices to just not have `return`s.

```
val results: List<AccountDto> = listOfPersons
                .map(::getPersonAccount)
                .filter { account ->
                    if(validateAccount(account)) {
                        // etc.
                        true
                    } else {
                        // etc.
                        false
                    }
                }
                .map(::toDto)
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the complete examples! I changed the accepted answer to this one since it is much more complete.

Answer (score 4):

You get that error because a plain `return` in a lambda tends to return from the outermost scope, the function itself.

Lambdas expect either implicit returns (the last expression on each path of execution) or explicit labelled returns `return@filter`.

Removing the `return`s or replacing them with `return@filter` will fix the error.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of that. As you can see I am a Kotlin noob ;)